# VBA Last Row errors

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this code, but columns with last row (A,B,K,L) fill in with 0 beyond the defined last row. Additionally, my transaction and type occasionally stop working, but if anyone sees what i'm doing wrong i'd love to learn so i don't have this issue again.

```
 Sub test()
Dim lastRow As Long
    

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

    'delete blank columns
    Range("W:W,U:U,S:S,Q:Q,O:O,M:M,K:K,I:I,G:G,E:E,C:C,A:A").Select
    Range("A1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

      'filter for blanks
    Range("A:L").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="="
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
      Selection.AutoFilter
 'Trans
    Columns("A:A").Select
       Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
       Range("A2:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
       Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
  'Type 
 Columns("B:B").Select
       Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
     Range("B2:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        Columns("B:B").Select
       Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False 
   'Debit
   Range("K2:K" & lastRow).Select
     'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
           ReplaceFormat:=False
    'credit
       Range("L2:L" & lastRow).Select
        'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
               
End Sub
```

Comment: You determine the `lastRow` in column J (columns(10)). `Range("K2:K" & lastRow)` will include all cells in column K from K2 to the last used row of column J. BTW, if you were to remove all *Activate* and *Select* commands and replace the `Selection` object with `Range` objects (instead of working with both most of the time) your code would shrink to about half its present size and run 10 times faster.

Comment: You need to bring the line `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row` after you delete blanks (i.e. just before `'Trans`

Comment: What do you mean by "my transaction and type occasionally stop working"? What exactly stops working?

Answer (score -1):

So sorry for my English, just get you wrong

Try to use cycle instead of replace.
Use `Dim EmptCell as range` once.

```
Dim EmptCell as range
For Each EmptCell in Range("youRange").Cells
If EmptCell.value = "" Then EmptCell.value = 0
Next EmptCell
```

And try to not to use selection. Work directly with a ranges, or use variables like you did with LastRow.

Small example below.

```
 '  Trans 
Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "General" 
Range("A2:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
 Columns("A:A").value = Columns("A:A").value
```

And I'm definitely recommend to change LastRow algorithm to this bulletproof one.
© https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/12882709

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lastrow = 1
    End If
```